# PHP 7 : How to generate zend_string variable of length 0

Tags: php-7, php-internals

I am working in PHP 7, I have a case in which i want to pass a string of length 0. so how can we generate zend_string variable of length 0.

I tried assigning NULL to zend_string variable but down the line code crashed because it is trying to dereference NULL. so I am guessing we need to allocate memory to zend_string variable and whole value NULL or string length is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick scan of the source shows a few examples of this:

```
zend_string *str;
str = zend_string_alloc(sizeof("") - 1, 0);
```

Comment: Unless you actually do need a new allocation, the correct way is using `ZSTR_EMPTY_ALLOC()`, which will return an interned string. (The name is bad, it does not allocate anything.)

Comment: Nice, thanks, my answer was just a grep and guess. :)

Comment: I tried above both methods but did not solved my issue. I'll Explain scenario again. Earlier in PHP 5 zval->value.str used to be a char array but in php7 it is modified to zend_string* type. My requirement is zend_string* variable should have the length of certain value let say 5 but its value should be NULL.

Comment: That's abusive, surely you can find another way. If you can't allocate the string as 5 bytes long (zend_string_alloc(5, 0)), and null terminate at the first byte (ZSTR_VAL(s)[0] = 0).